# Spring: Side effects of @Async on Transactions handling?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, events, transactions

I have a Spring Boot REST API through which a web client can start the execution of a testsuite. The handling of the transactions was tricky, but i finally made it and everything work as expected. This is my setting:

- the http request is handled by a controller (1)
- when receiving the request, the controller publishes an event "start testsuite" (I use the Spring Event handling)
- a method with @EventListener (2) listens to that event and calls the method in charge of the testsuite execution (3).

Now it turns out that the execution of the testsuite is sometime very long. As I don't want the http request to remain pending too long, I'd like to make the testsuite execution asynchron. To achieve that I added a @Async at the method of the service layer in charge of the testsuite execution(3).

As a result: I can tell that the process runs now indeed async but the testsuite execution behave in a weird way that make me think the transactions are not handled correctly anymore. So what I'm trying to understand, and that's the object of this question: in which way the @Async can, in this configuration, have side effects on the transaction handling?

I did some research. According to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-transaction)

> If the @Async annotation is being used extra care should be taken with respect to transactions. In normal circumstances (without @Async) a transaction gets propagated through the call hierarchy from one Spring @Component to the other. However, when a @Transactional Spring @Component calls a method annotated with @Async this does not happen. The call to the asynchronous method is being scheduled and executed at a later time by a task executor and is thus handled as a 'fresh' call, i.e. without a transactional context. If the @Async method (or the @Component in which it is declared) is not @Transactional by itself Spring will not manage any needed transactions.

I get that point, but I don't think I'm in this situation since the calling method of the async method (= the event listener) has not been made transactional.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Yes, your thinking is generally correct. To provide further assistance, though, we would need to understand the kind of 'weird behaviour' you are experiencing

Comment: I didn't want to go to deep into the details of how the test execution itself works because it pretty complicated and would have made my question hard to read and understand. I kept it generic, so it can help others in the same situation. Basically I can say the weird behavior is linked to infos that are not retrieved from the DB. I also had this kind of troubles in the synch. version until I fixed the transaction handling.